# Mirror in scheme returns nested list w/o helper functions

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a list and returns the inverted list.

```
(define (mirror l)
    (if (< (length l) 2)
         (car l)
         (list (mirror (cdr l)) (car l))))
```

When I run `(mirror (list 1 2 3 4))` it returns `(((4 3) 2) 1)` where I am expecting `(4 3 2 1)`.
I'm relatively new to scheme so sorry if this is a simple mistake. Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: This is not a duplicate. I did not state before but we are not able to use helper functions.

Comment: Managed to fix it by changing the last line to `(append (mirror (cdr l)) (list (car l)))))`

Comment: `(define mirror reverse)`